# Print image in Zebra printer

Tags: image, label, zebra-printers

I've developed a system for generating an HTML tag and then converting it to a .PNG image.

I need to print this image on the Zebra printer, but I still don't have a printer, I'm testing with the Zpl Printer application and with the online ZPL Viewer at http://labelary.com/viewer.html.

My code is as follows: (C#)

```
var ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 9100;

var bitmapImagePath = @"C:\Users\super\Desktop\Capturar.png";

var bitmapDataFileSize = new FileInfo(bitmapImagePath).Length;

var bitmapData = File.ReadAllBytes(bitmapImagePath);

var hexadecimalString = BitConverter.ToString(bitmapData).Replace("-", string.Empty);

var widthInBytes = Math.Ceiling(bitmapDataFileSize/8.0);

var etiqueta = "^XA^FO0,0^GFA," + 
               bitmapDataFileSize + "," +
               bitmapDataFileSize + "," + 
               widthInBytes + "," +
               hexadecimalString + "^XZ";

// Open connection
var client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
client.Connect(ipAddress, port);

// Write ZPL String to connection
var writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
writer.Write(etiqueta);

// Close Connection
writer.Close();
client.Close();

return etiqueta;
```

The Zpl Printer displays the message that received a few bytes from the client, but doesn't display anything.

I'm getting the ZPL return from my code and testing on the Labelary website and there it shows the label but in the wrong format.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, how to fix the label size and why not show up in the ZPL Printer app.

Note: the correct size is 3 x 14 cm.
Here is an example image:

[image: ExemploEtiqueta]

Comment: Did you get the solution ? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you please try https://github.com/BinaryKits/ZPLUtility ?